# django dynamic form ValueError

Tags: django, forms

I want to get the select form which can display all the users who have the group name "sale".
My definition for my forms is like this:

```
class ArrangeUserForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArrangeUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user_choices = []
        for user in User.objects.all():
            if user.groups.filter(name="sale"):
                user_choices.append(user.first_name)
        self.fields['user_field'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=user_choices)

    mobile = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, max_length=11, min_length=11)
```

and my view is like this:

```
class ArrangeUserHandler(View):
def get(self, request):
    form = ArrangeUserForm()
    return render(request, 'student/student_form.html', {'form': form,})

def post(self, request):
    pass
```

when I run my code and request for that view, I got the following error:

ValueError at /student/arrangeuser/

too many values to unpack

could anyone told me what's going wrong here?

Traceback:

```
request Method: GET
Request URL: http://domain/student/arrangeuser/

Django Version: 1.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'accounts',
 'student',
 'order')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/rogerliu/newproject/crm/templates/student/student_form.html, error at line 7
   too many values to unpack
   1 :


   2 : <form method="post">


   3 :         {% csrf_token %}


   4 :         {% for field in form %}


   5 :                 <div class="fieldWrapper">


   6 :                         {{ field.errors }}


   7 :                         {{ field.label_tag }}:  {{ field }}


   8 :                 </div>


   9 :         {% endfor %}


   10 :         <input type="submit" value="submit" />


   11 :


   12 : </form>

   13 :


   14 :

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  86.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/rogerliu/newproject/crm/student/views.py" in get
  318.         return render(request, 'student/student_form.html', {'form': form,})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  177.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  188.                         nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render
  87.             output = force_text(output)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  99.                 s = s.__unicode__()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in __str__
  411.         return self.as_widget()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in as_widget
  458.         return widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in render
  555.         options = self.render_options(choices, [value])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in render_options
  579.         for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):

Exception Type: ValueError at /student/arrangeuser/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack
```

~

Comment: Could you add full traceback.

Comment: ok, I will add it soon

Comment: shouldn't choices be a hash? try `tuple(enumerate(user_choices))`

Comment: It's a pitty I can't vote for you, it works, thank you Hedde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, choices needs to be a key, value mapping, use:

```
tuple(enumerate(user_choices))
```

Answer (score 0):

My questions are: How did you define your models?
Can you get the users from the group?
Can you get the groups from the user?
something like that:

```
groups = Group.objects.get(pk=1)
groups.users

user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
user.groups
```

You can do that writing this in you code:

```
#models.py
class User(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=200)

class Group(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=200)
    users = ManyToManyField(User, related_name="groups")

#forms.py
class ArrangeUserForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArrangeUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        groups = groups.objects.filter(name="sale")
        user_choices = User.objects.filter(groups_in=groups)
        self.fields['user_field'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=user_choices)

    mobile = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, max_length=11, min_length=11)

#And you views.py
class ArrangeUserHandler(FormView):
    form_class = ArrangeUserForm
    template_name = 'student/student_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #When the form is valid
        return super(ArrangeUserHandler, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        #When the form is invalid
        return super(ArrangeUserHandler, self).form_invalid(form)
```

I think that It should work fine and quickly. 
Will you tell me if this lines work?

```
# ...
groups = groups.objects.filter(name="sale")
user_choices = User.objects.filter(groups_in=groups)
# ...
```

I hope that helps.
see the Documentation of  [ManyToMany field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) and
[FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/)  if you are in django 1.5

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Hedde answered earlier and solved the problem, so I can only accept his answer:)

Comment: No problem, but consider re write your queries, yo are making `User.objects.all()` and `user.groups.filter(name="sale")` for every user in db. You are getting all user objects, then making foreach and making queries by everyone. I'm making 2 queries `groups.objects.filter(name="sale")` and `User.objects.filter(groups_in=groups)`. This is quickly and readable. See you!